# Show input on checkbox check dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

how can I show the text input if the checkbox is checked off in each div?

For example, if I check the first checkbox, I want the "name" input to show. If I check the checkbox in the last div, i want it to show the "phone" checkbox. how can i do that with css or javascript or jquery?

Here is my code:

```html
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="hidden">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="hidden">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see you have tagged `javascript` but I don't see any attempt(s) of your own? Please include your own attempt(s) even if those attempt(s) work or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use js/jquery to attach an event to checkboxes, in the event handler simply `toggle()` the next '.hidden'. something like this will work:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
   $(this).next('.hidden').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text" name="name" class="hidden">
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text" name="email" class="hidden">
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text" name="phone" class="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: Accepted answer, you were 1 millisecond faster

Comment: how would it work if I changed it from `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: then you will have to use `$(this).next('.hidden').css('visibility', 'visible')`

Comment: how can i hide it on the next click? like toggle?

Comment: you will need some if conditions inside event handler to toggle visibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toggle()` on input `next` of clicked checkbox on `change` event.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle()
})
```

```css
input.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="hidden">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="text" name="email" class="hidden">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="text" name="phone" class="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: how would it work if I changed it from `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden`?